# localStorage save session object

Tags: javascript, session, local-storage

I am trying to load user data from database on the server which the app retrieves into `localStorage` but after successful login, the program is not saving the session at all. I have tested repeatedly - checked Typo's and tried to convert from object to plain array but i keep getting the same error:

> Error: Saving to local storage. 80$00#nf Error: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'split' of undefined

This is the function i am using to store the session data

```
function SaveSession($AjaxData) {

    if (!!window.localStorage) 
    {   
        try {
       //Saving array data to local storage
        var client = new Object();
        var ArrLngth = $AjaxData.length;
        var categories = [ "FullName", "CompanyName", "Profession", "cell", "country", "usern", "email", "passw"];
        var $l = 0;
        var $AjaxSplit = [];

            while($l <= ArrLngth) {
                $AjaxSplit = $AjaxData[$l].split(" = "); 
                found = $k.inArray($AjaxSplit[0], categories);

                if(found != '-1')   {
                    switch(found)                   
                    {
                        case 0:
                            client.Fullname = $AjaxSplit[1];
                        break;

                        case 1:
                            client.Company =  $AjaxSplit[1];
                        break;

                        case 2:
                            client.Title = $AjaxSplit[1];
                        break;

                        case 3:
                            client.Mobile =  $AjaxSplit[1];
                        break;

                        case 4:
                            client.country =  $AjaxSplit[1];
                        break;

                        case 5:
                            client.usern =  $AjaxSplit[1];              
                        break;

                        case 6:
                            client.email =  $AjaxSplit[1];
                        break;

                        case 7:
                            client.password =  $AjaxSplit[1];
                        break;

                    }

                }

                $l++;
            }

        window.localStorage.setItem("client", JSON.stringify(client));
        } 
        catch (exception) {
                console.log("Error: Saving to local storage.\n\r " +client.password+" Error: "+exception);
        }
    }
    else {
        alert('ERRROR Local not supported!!!'); 
    }

};
```

I have tried storing data values individually too... Anything I'm missing or not doing correctly?

Comment: the condition `$l <= ArrLngth` should be `$l < ArrLngth` I guess because `$AjaxData[$AjaxData.length]` would return undefined

Comment: @GeraldoIsaaks why don't you just save full user information? just serialize it, `localStorage.setItem('ajax_data', JSON.stringify($AjaxData));`

Comment: @evc there are some results i want to screen out - for admin use only...